# Mocking Angular 9 Services with Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular9

With Angular 7, I'm able to mock my `SearchService` with Jasmine by creating a few classes. The first is a `helper.ts` file that has a class you can extend.

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts"‌​/>

export interface GuinessCompatibleSpy extends jasmine.Spy {
  /** By chaining the spy with and.returnValue, all calls to the function will return a specific
   * value. */
  andReturn(val: any): void;
  /** By chaining the spy with and.callFake, all calls to the spy will delegate to the supplied
   * function. */
  andCallFake(fn: Function): GuinessCompatibleSpy;
  /** removes all recorded calls */
  reset();
}

export class SpyObject {
  static stub(object = null, config = null, overrides = null) {
    if (!(object instanceof SpyObject)) {
      overrides = config;
      config = object;
      object = new SpyObject();
    }

    const m = {};
    Object.keys(config).forEach((key) => m[key] = config[key]);
    Object.keys(overrides).forEach((key) => m[key] = overrides[key]);
    for (const key in m) {
      object.spy(key).andReturn(m[key]);
    }
    return object;
  }

  constructor(type = null) {
    if (type) {
      for (const prop in type.prototype) {
        let m = null;
        try {
          m = type.prototype[prop];
        } catch (e) {
          // As we are creating spys for abstract classes,
          // these classes might have getters that throw when they are accessed.
          // As we are only auto creating spys for methods, this
          // should not matter.
        }
        if (typeof m === 'function') {
          this.spy(prop);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  spy(name) {
    if (!this[name]) {
      this[name] = this._createGuinnessCompatibleSpy(name);
    }
    return this[name];
  }

  prop(name, value) { this[name] = value; }

  /** @internal */
  _createGuinnessCompatibleSpy(name): GuinessCompatibleSpy {
    const newSpy: GuinessCompatibleSpy = <any>jasmine.createSpy(name);
    newSpy.andCallFake = <any>newSpy.and.callFake;
    newSpy.andReturn = <any>newSpy.and.returnValue;
    newSpy.reset = <any>newSpy.calls.reset;
    // revisit return null here (previously needed for rtts_assert).
    newSpy.and.returnValue(null);
    return newSpy;
  }
}
```

Here is the `search.service.ts` I'm trying to test:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get('assets/data/people.json');
  }

  search(q: string): Observable<any> {
    // implementation
  }

  get(id: number) {
    // implementation
  }

  save(person: Person) {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

And here's my `search.service.mock.ts`:

```
import { SpyObject } from './helper';
import { SearchService } from '../search.service';
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;

export class MockSearchService extends SpyObject {
  getAllSpy: Spy;
  getByIdSpy: Spy;
  searchSpy: Spy;
  saveSpy: Spy;
  fakeResponse: any;

  constructor() {
    super(SearchService);

    this.fakeResponse = null;
    this.getAllSpy = this.spy('getAll').andReturn(this);
    this.getByIdSpy = this.spy('get').andReturn(this);
    this.searchSpy = this.spy('search').andReturn(this);
    this.saveSpy = this.spy('save').andReturn(this);
  }

  subscribe(callback: any) {
    callback(this.fakeResponse);
  }

  setResponse(json: any): void {
    this.fakeResponse = json;
  }
}
```

And then I mock it in a test.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import { MockSearchService } from '../shared/search/mocks/search.service';
import { MockActivatedRoute, MockRouter } from '../shared/search/mocks/routes';
import { SearchService } from '../shared';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;
  let mockSearchService: MockSearchService;
  let mockActivatedRoute: MockActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockSearchService = new MockSearchService();
    mockActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute({'term': 'peyton'});

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SearchComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: SearchService, useValue: mockSearchService},
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute}
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This works with Angular 7. However, when I try it with Angular 9, I have to remove the `// <reference path="..."/>` at the top of `helper.ts` to fix some compiler errors.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:25:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ImplementationCallback, Func, Constructor, ExpectedRecursive, Expected, SpyObjMethodNames, CustomEqualityTester, CustomMatcherFactory, ExpectationFailed, SpecFunction, SpyObj, jasmine

25 type ImplementationCallback = jasmine.ImplementationCallback;
   ~~~~
```

Then I get two errors:

```
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.15.1) SearchComponent should create FAILED
    Failed: this.getSpy is not a function
        at <Jasmine>
```

And:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[SearchService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'SearchService', 'HttpClient', 'HttpClient' ] })
```

Any idea why this works in Angular 7 and not in Angular 9?

The app that works with Angular 7 is on GitHub at https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo.

Comment: why are you creating Mocks on your own instead of using:
`{ provide: SearchService, useClass: MockSearchService }` and `RouterTestingModule` https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule

Comment: I need to set it myself so I can refer to it later in tests. For example: `expect(mockSearchService.searchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('M');`

Comment: you can do the same whe you take out them from TesBed like this: `const someMock = TestBed.get<MockSearchService>(SearchService)` or via `inject([SearchService], (searchService: MockSearchService) => {...})`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. Using `useClass` has the same results. Here's my test: https://gist.github.com/mraible/6799ef0f466ff062f47c5c86b942a80b. It still results in `TypeError: this.getSpy is not a function`. I'm not sure where this is coming from. I tried renaming the `get()` method in my service to `getById()`, but the error stays the same.

Comment: this error `R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[SearchService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:` probably could be solved with use of `HttpTestingModule` https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule
But i have hard time understanding why you need that extending `SpyObject ` or that `SpyObject ` at all.

Comment: Ok i think I have now wage idea why I that whole `getSpy` looks like something that is somwhere inside jasmine so maybe they changed versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided it'd be easier to get rid of `helper.ts` and mock what's returned by the service. I also changed to import `HttpClientTestingModule` so the service can be instantiated, even if its `HttpClient` is never used. Here's my `search.component.spec.ts` after this refactoring:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import { MockActivatedRoute } from '../shared/search/mocks/routes';
import { SearchService } from '../shared';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;
  let mockActivatedRoute: MockActivatedRoute;
  let mockSearchService: SearchService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute({term: 'nikola'});

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute}
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    // mock response
    mockSearchService = TestBed.inject(SearchService);
    mockSearchService.search = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of([]));

    // initialize component
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should search when a term is set and search() is called', () => {
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    component.query = 'J';
    component.search();
    expect(mockSearchService.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('J');
  });

  it('should search automatically when a term is on the URL', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(mockSearchService.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('nikola');
  });
});
```

For another test, I did something similar, returning expected data from the service.

```
import { EditComponent } from './edit.component';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Address, Person, SearchService } from '../shared';
import { MockRouter, MockActivatedRoute } from '../shared/search/mocks/routes';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('EditComponent', () => {
  let mockSearchService: SearchService;
  let mockActivatedRoute: MockActivatedRoute;
  let mockRouter: MockRouter;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute({id: 1});
    mockRouter = new MockRouter();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EditComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute},
        {provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter}
      ],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();

    mockSearchService = TestBed.inject(SearchService);
  });

  it('should fetch a single record', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditComponent);

    const person = new Person({id: 1, name: 'Gary Harris'});
    person.address = new Address({city: 'Denver'});

    // mock response
    spyOn(mockSearchService, 'get').and.returnValue(of(person));

    // initialize component
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // verify service was called
    expect(mockSearchService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);

    // verify data was set on component when initialized
    const editComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(editComponent.editAddress.city).toBe('Denver');

    // verify HTML renders as expected
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h3').innerHTML).toBe('Gary Harris');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Had NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError in a spec.ts which runs fine in Angular 8. The test creates a mock @Injectable service.

In Angular 9, the stack trace shows that the Ivy compiler is trying to create the real service, and eventually fails because that service has further dependencies.

As a temporary workaround, disabling Ivy resolves the issue

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
}
```

(Beware that this might need to be set in tsconfig.json, or tsconfig.spec.json, depending on your setup)